# How to prevent Apps.Microsoft.com cookies with iframe sandbox?

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-store

I would like to embed the Microsoft Store (our App page) into our web site, but I don't want them to create any cookies. How can I display Microsoft App Store information without allowing them to make some tracking cookies.

I have enabled SANDBOX feature like this:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/APP NAME">
```

Comment: I don't think what you want, is possible. `allow-same-origin` is about scripting access, but it does not prevent cookies to be set via HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking the cookies will likely violate the terms of using the MS store, so whilst their are convoluted ways to do this, they are probably not legal, unless you first negotiate a contract with MicroSoft.